# how to share objects between sibling components using services?

Tags: javascript, angular

I need to call a service on a component, and ideally this service would fetch info in another 2 or 3 components (which already are communicated with the database, etc). I need to be able to share objects.

I've created a service called DashService, like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class DashService {

  constructor() { }

}
```

I've linked it to the component that will us it, and I also imported and added the service name in the 'providers' part of the NgModule.
Added:

```
Import { OnInit } from '@angular/core';
```

and

```
implements OnInit{...}
```

on the module that will send info to the service.

I dont know how to go forward. How can I share an object that exists on a component, to my service? I fail to set the Constructor correctly (on the component sending the info)

When I try

```
public constructor( private DashService: DashService)
```

I get an error telling me 'DashService refers to a value but is being used as a type'

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Tried reading the official [docs](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service)?

Comment: In my limited understanding this would be a sibling components type of case, wouldnt it?

Answer (score 1):

Because you are calling the service as the type of the service!

Just change the name, usually the first letter of the service is in lowercase

```
public constructor( private dashService: DashService)
```

https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service
here you can find an example how to communicate between components.In general for parent/child components you can use @Input / @Output decorator.
For others case you can use a service ( or a any state management)

Comment: Thank you. That was dumb. Do you have any insight on how to share an object with the service?

Comment: @dizzydizzy The way to share data with components and services is with Observables. You put the data into an Observable (usually a BehaviorSubject) on the service. And then you tell the component to use that Observable by injecting the service to use it. And then, if you have a service that needs some other data, it just needed to get access to the Observable that contains the data.

Answer (score 0):

Riccardo Gai is right, you should do that to use a service, 
`public constructor( private dashService: DashService)`

But to answer your question, in order to be able to share data between components through a service, you should create an object in that service, for example a public object, then you can access that object through the service.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class DashService {

  objectToShareHere: any;

  constructor() { }

}
```

I think anyway, the best way of this to work is to have get and set methods and access the object through them (having a private obj). Like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class DashService {

  private objectToShareHere: any;

  constructor() { }

  setPrivateObj(obj) {
     this.objectToShareHere = obj;
  }

  getPrivateObj() {
     return this.objectToShareHere;
  }

}
```

If the data you need to share is from a BE, you can use a Subject object (see [RxJs subject](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/subject) here)